# How to sleep python script for xx minutes after every hour execution?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a python script that works in a loop mode with iteration through a text file to run for periods of one hour and make 30minute pauses between each hour loop .

After some searching I found this piece of code :

```
import datetime
import time

delta_hour = 0

while:
    now_hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour

    if delta_hour != now_hour:
        # run your code

    delta_hour = now_hour

    time.sleep(1800) # 1800 seconds sleep

    # add some way to exit the infinite loop
```

This code has a few issues though :

1. It does not consider one hour periods since the script starts running
2. It does not seem to work continuously for periods over one hour

Considering what I am trying to achieve (running script 1hour before each time it pauses for 30mins) what is the best approach to this ? Cron is not an option here .

For clarification :

1hour run -- 30min pause -- repeat

Thanks

Comment: For me it is not clear what you want to do. Do you want to (a) run a script 1 hour prior to the pauses? Or do you want to run a script for 1 hour and sleep for 30 minutes?

Comment: This script does nothing for 90 minutes, then runs your script, then pauses for 90 minutes again. The hour will always change with this long an interval, so that part of the test does nothing after the first go-round.

Comment: I believe OP wants to work for 60 minutes, rest for 30, repeat.

Comment: I would schedule as tasks using an appropriate library. https://schedulemanager.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html#start-task-at-particular-time as an example.

Comment: @cvanelteren yes exactly, I want to run for 1hour then pause 30mins and repeat the loop.

Comment: why dont you use cron to schedule your job?

Comment: Consider kicking off a new thread every time you want to start operation. Then your main thread becomes responsible _only_ for timing startup, and it doesn't get thrown off by drift in how long operations take to actually complete.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra, ...on modern systems, one has considerably better OS-vendor-provided tools than cron -- see in particular systemd timers on Linux; I believe launchd in MacOS has something similar as well.

Comment: Perhaps placing this code inside my main thread works ?

if int(time() - start_time >= 60 * 60):
            sleep(30 * 60)
            print ("sleep time")

Comment: @JatinMehrotra I am running this script on windows , I mentioned in the OP that cron was not an option :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest solution I could come up with was the following piece of code, which I added inside my main thread :

```
start_time = int(time())
... #main thread code
#main thread code end
if int(time() - start_time >= 60 * 60):
    print("pausing time")
    sleep(30 * 60)
    start_time = int(time())
```

From the moment the script starts this will pause every hour for 30mins and resume afterwards .

Simple yet effective !

Answer (score 1):

Here is a so simple code, I have written for teaching purposes, which is very clear

```
from datetime import datetime

class control_process():

    def __init__(self, woking_period, sleeping_period):
        self.woking_period = woking_period  # working period in minutes
        self.sleeping_period = sleeping_period  # sleeping period in minutes
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.start_time = datetime.utcnow()  # set starting point

    def manage(self):
        m = (datetime.utcnow() - self.start_time).seconds / 60  # how long since starting point
        if m >= self.woking_period:  # if exceeded the working period
            time.sleep(self.sleeping_period * 60)  # time to sleep in seconds
            self.reset() # then reset time again
        return  # go to continue working


cp = control_process(60, 30)  # release for 60 minutes and sleep for 30 minutes

while True:  # you code loop
    cp.manage()
    '''
    your code
    '''
```

in which 'control_process`object - I called`cp`- calls`cp.manage()` inside your executing loop.

you reset time via `cp.reset()` before going in the loop or whenever you want

***Based on Comments***
The simplicity I mean is to add this class to your general library so you can use it whenever you want by instantiation of cp then one or two controlling functions 'cp.manage()` which control the working cycles, and cp.reset() if you want to use it in another location of the code. I believe that use a function is better than a long condition statement.

Comment: Thanks Nour, this solution works !

However, I found a much simpler way to achieve this which I will add in an answer for further reference .

Comment: Thank @Opitmus, the simplicity I mean is to add this class to your general library so you can use it whenever you want by instantiation of `cp` then one or two controlling functions 'cp.manage()` which control the working cycles, and `cp.reset()` if you want to use it in another location of the code. I believe that use a function is better than a long condition statement.

Answer (score 0):

Using the default library you could do something like call the script itself using `subprocess`. By checking whether conditions are met the process could do a task and call itself. Extending the logic with a kill pill would make it stop (I leave that up to you).

```py
import argparse, time
from subprocess import call

DELAY = 60 * 30 # minutes
WORK_TIME = 60 * 60  # minutes
parser =  argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-s",
                    help = "interval start time",
                    type = float,
                    default = time.time())
parser.add_argument("-t",
                    help = "interval stop time",
                    type = float,
                    default = time.time() + WORK_TIME)

def do_task():
    # implement task
    print("working..")
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args  = parser.parse_args()

    start = args.s
    stop = args.t
    # work
    if start < time.time() < stop:
        do_task()
    # shift target
    else:
        start = time.time() + DELAY
        stop =  start + WORK_TIME
    call(f"python test.py -t {stop} -s {start}".split())
```

Comment: Thanks but the script should not be stopped, it just needs to pause running because once it stops it will lost all the list iteration data .

So this is a possible solution if maintaining the script running is not important .

Comment: The original post list nothing of keeping track of data. The code I wrote dump intermittent results to disk. It has the advantage that it does not depend on the running time of the task. I am not sure what the context of the request is, if it is waiting on another process to generate data other approaches are more advised.